# Changing the name of a component in Adobe CQ

Tags: aem, day-cq

I'm using Adobe CQ5. I copied the 'image' component from 'foundation/components/image' into my component folder. Now I want to rename this component to something else, say 'xyz'.
I changed the name of the node to 'xyz', also I renamed  image.jsp to xyz.jsp , however this doesn't seem to work. 
Can you please list down all the changes that I need to make in order to make this work?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are facing when using the new component? Kindly add a bit more info to the question.

Comment: Also, please specify how much of the code you have copied from the foundation folder.  Everything, including the dialog.xml and the design_dialog.xml?  Or just the image.jsp?

Comment: @DavidGorsline +1 — would be helpful if you gave an outline of your file/folder structure & defined what "doesn't seem to work" means :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was setting the jcr:title value to "xyz". Turns out that this value should start with a `capital letter`. Everything is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Title of the component displayed in the sidekick could be set using `jcr:title` property on the main component node (`image` node in your case).

Answer (score 0):

If you have cq edit config xml file make sure you add right component group and make sure that this is enabled by going to design mode.
I am just guessing this because these are some of the common mistakes. As suggested from other please add more details.